# css float drop in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

i have a wordpress theme with the following layout:

- main-wrap
- content on the left inside the main-wrap
- sidebar on the right inside the main warp

If the Browser window is wide enough the sidebar is shown beside the content but if the browser width goes under a certain pixel value the sidebar moves below the content.

What i want to achieve is that the sidebar stays beside the content and "overflows hidden" when the browser becomes to "narrow".

Here is the part of the style.css file that represents those elements:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  General Structure
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    color:#5F5C52;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#main-wrap {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 20px;
    padding:30px 0 55px;
}
#sidebar {
    padding-top:80px;
    float:right;
}
#content {
    float:left;
}

/* ---  Layout Options --- */
.one-column #content,
.one-column #sidebar {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:960px;
    border-left: none;
}
.one-column #sidebar {
    padding-top:110px;
    text-align:center;
}
.one-column #sidebar #searchform {
    display:inline-block;
}
.one-column #content .post,
.one-column #sidebar .widget {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by overflow:hidden for the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#sidebar {
    padding-top:80px;
    float:right;
}
```

To this:

```
#sidebar {
    padding-top:80px;
    float:right;
    position: fixed;
}
```